# Calling a custom JSP tag from JSTL tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm trying to call my custom tag from the JSTL tag `<c:url>`.
Because of the quotes, the custom tag is shown as a string instead of a tag.
Can I use an escape character here?

```
<img align="left" src="<c:url value='/getFile/getfile?<myTag:getValue type="web"  name="person" />'/>" alt="person" title="person" width="55" height="70"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to assign the output of your custom tag to a temp variable first and then use it

```
<c:set var="urlquerystring"><myTag:getValue type="web" name="person" /></c:set>

<img align="left" src="<c:url value='/getFile/getfile?${urlquerystring}'/>" alt="person" title="person" width="55" height="70"/>
```