# Best way to call one custom JSP tag from inside another custom JSP tag?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

We are trying to implement additional cross site scripting protection in our app using the [OWASP Java Encoder Project's custom tag library](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project#tab=Use_the_Java_Encoder_Project).  On the proof-of-concept page I'm working on, I've run into the problem of how to use the `e:forHtml` tag inside an existing tag, in this case the Spring `form:input` tag:

```
<form:input id="Quantity_${status.index}" path="<e:forHtml value=${myData.items[status.index].quantity} />" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
```

I was told that this should be OK, but when I try this I get the following runtime error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: 
Invalid property '<e:forHtml value=1 />' of bean class [com.mystuff.MyData]: 
Bean property '<e:forHtml value=1 />' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: 
Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Is it possible to do this, or should I re-implement this another way?

Comment: Does the `<e:forHtml [..]>` tag work, if you use it outside of the declaration of the other tag?

Comment: did you try to path="<e:forHtml value='${myData.items[status.index].quantity}' />" or path=<e:forHtml value="${myData.items[status.index].quantity}" />

Comment: @t0mppa - yes, the annotation works fine.   After looking at this some more, the problem, I think, is that the path="" attribute is actually passing, not a value, but the name of the field that will be evaluated to get the actual value.   So I don't believe there's any possibility of this working this way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get it to work with using a variable:

```html
<c:set var="myPath"><e:forHtml value="${myData.items[status.index].quantity}" /></c:set>

<form:input id="Quantity_${status.index}" path="${myPath}" size="4"
            maxlength="4"/>
```

But this basically makes the question a duplicate of [Calling a custom JSP tag from JSTL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785280/calling-a-custom-jsp-tag-from-jstl-tag?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, no - after some more investigation the Spring form:input tag actually needs the string value "myData.items[status.index].quantity" because it's going to go back into the data and use that to grab a particular field.   So, I had to do this a different way.   But thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to protect the static string: "mydata.items[status.index].quantity" from cross-site scripting, by escaping HTML in it? What on earth for, if I may ask?

Comment: No, the string has an EL expression in it normally.   I was tasked with encoding all EL expressions to prevent cross site scripting.  The item normally looks like `"myData.items[${status.index}].quantity"`.   Fair enough?

Comment: Tasked with encoding all EL expressions to prevent cross site scripting, eh? Did you at any point bother questioning such advice or consider not taking it literally? `status` here looks like a loop variable from `forEach`, so how on earth could it hold any vulnerabilities? Also, you say above that you had to do this in a different way, you should post that as an answer then.