# i18n in form select (Spring MVC 3.2.8)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization, jstl

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.
I want to use a message inside a form:select, but I got an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property  `'<fmt:message key=' of bean class`
```

The JSP

```
  <form:select path="cancelledSubStatus" 
                                                     id="cancelledSubStatusId"
                                                     items="${cancelledSubStates}" 
                                                     itemValue="key" 
                                                     itemLabel="<fmt:message key="${key}" />"
                                                     cssClass="c-select"

                                                     />
```

Comment: Use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785280/calling-a-custom-jsp-tag-from-jstl-tag. I don't think you can nest these tags.

Comment: `fmt:message` does expose a `var` that you can access through EL.

Answer (score 2):

outside of the form you can do:

```
<fmt:message key="your.message" var="ItemLabelMessage" />
```

so you are saving the message in that variable and then inside of the form select you access that variable by doing:

```
itemLabel="${ItemLabelMessage}"
```

There it should work

Hope it works! Good luck